# probability ambiguous notation

Tags: probability, notation

**Part A)**

I have the following notations :

1. $p(\mu, \sigma^2)$
2. $N(x)$
3. $p(x | \mu, \sigma^2)$

I would read them in the following manner:

1. probability function with 2 parameters, namely $\mu$
   and $\sigma^2$
2. normal distribution of variable $x$
3. distribution of variable $x$ with parameters $\mu$
   and $\sigma^2$

**Part B)**

If the above is correct, then please check my interpretation of :

1. $p(x,y)$
2. $p(x | y,a,b,c,d)$

my interpretation :

1. probabilty function of 2 independent variables
2. probability of variable $x$, given the probability for $y$ and parameters $a,b,c$ are known

**Part C)**

The follwoing notation is equal

$p(y∣x)$ is equal to  $p_{Y∣X}(y∣x)$ is equal to $P(Y=y∣X=x)$

and the above notaitons in **Part A** and **Part B** can be rewritten in similar manner.

---

I would conclude my understanding as follows:

$p(variable|parameters)$

where the $variable$ is the input to the function $p(x)$, and the $parameters$ are the parameters of $p(...)$ and as such, need to be known prior to the evaluation of $p(x)$

Comment: There are unfortunately no unified notations in the math world, so we cannot actually know what for example $p(x,y)$ means in Your class.

Comment: sure, therefore I have formulated the question as it is, asking whether the my interpretation is correct, not the only possible.